# why should I declare the command again in `activationEvents` filed of package.json?

Tags: vscode-extensions

as the sample says

```
// this method is called when your extension is activated
// your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
```

so I register the command at the `activationEvents` again?

kind of counterintuitive.

Comment: Commands are defined in `package.json` so that VSCode knows what they are and when to activate them (`activationEvents`) in the place. The code you have in `activate` is only called afterwards, to hook actual methods to them.

Comment: for me, it feels like register command two times,  one is when you write `active` hooks, one is in `activationEvents`,   I think just put it in `contributes.command` field is fine,  then when you invoke it from the Command Palette,  trigger the `active` hooks immediately

Answer (score 1):

It became unnecessary to put your commands into the `activationEvents` part of your `package.json` with vscode v1.74 Stable.  From [v1.74 Release Notes: implicit activation events](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_74.md#implicit-activation-events-for-declared-extension-contributions):

> #### Implicit activation events for declared extension contributions
>
> This milestone we removed the requirement to explicitly list
> activation events if your extension declares certain extension
> contributions in its `package.json`.
>
> Previously, if an extension declared that it contributed a command
> `mycommand` in its `package.json` file, it also needed to list the
> corresponding `onCommand:mycommand` activation event in the
> `activationEvents` field of `package.json` for the command to
> successfully execute. This was tedious and error-prone and could lead
> to large `package.json` files.
>
> VS Code will now automatically populate activation events for the
> following extension contribution points:

```
onCommand
onAuthenticationRequest
onLanguage
onCustomEditor
onView
```

> Extension authors can now safely remove these inferred activation
> events from your extensions. If you do so, update your VS Code engine
> requirement to ensure that your extension is not treated as compatible
> with earlier versions of VS Code:
>
> ````json
>     "engines": {
>         "vscode": "^1.74.0"
>     }, ```
> ````